# chown command returning Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb-drive, chown, fat

I am working on a raspberry pi and am having a tough time giving permissions to an external hard drive that I have mounted using the following tutorial:

http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/

I have now created folders on that external hard drive and when I do a `ls -l` command I get the following returned:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 512 Aug 28 23:24 test
```

That is located in: `/media/USBHDD1/shares`

Now I'm trying to give it all write read and execute permissions or even change the owner and group to pi:pi

However, `chmod 777` is not working – it doesn't return an error, just seems to have no effect

And when I use

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi test/
```

I get the error

```
chown: changing ownership of `test/': Operation not permitted
```

This is a linux question but I think someone with background and knowledge of using a raspberry pi can help me out here.

Extra info as requested:

When I run `pi@raspberrypi /media $  grep USBHDD1 /etc/mtab`
it returns:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD1 vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Comment: Looks like `/media/USBHDD1` is a NTFS or VFAT partition which has the user/group ownership configured at mount time.

Comment: Either that, or it is mounted read-only. To the OP: what is the mountpoint? ( `/media/USBHDD1/shares/` or  `/media/USBHDD1/` ? ) and What is the `pwd` when issuing the chmod command ?

Comment: Include the output of `grep USBHDD1 /etc/mtab` in your question.

Comment: @wildplasser I believe the mountpoint is /media/USBHDD1/shares and Im not prompted for a password when using chmod. Any command I use 'sudo' in, Im never prompted for a password

Comment: VFAT ist is. @myninjaname was right. VFAT does not support ownership.

Comment: @wildplasser how can I change this to not be VFAT then? Is that a possible solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason is because the ownership and permissions are defined at mount time for the `vfat` FS.

> Manual page mount(8):
>
> Mount options for fat ..
>
> ```
>    uid=value and gid=value
>
>           Set the owner and group of all files.  (Default: the uid and gid
>           of the current process.)
>
>    umask=value
>
>           Set the umask (the bitmask  of  the  permissions  that  are  not
>           present).  The default is the umask of the current process.  The
>           value is given in octal.
> ```

There are at least three things you can do:

(1) Give `pi:pi` access to the entire /media/USBHDD1 mount:

`mount -o remount,gid=<pi's gid>,uid=<pi's uid> /media/USBHDD1`

To determine pi's uid:

`cat /etc/passwd |grep pi`

To determine pi's gid:

`cat /etc/group |grep pi`

(2) Give everyone access to `/media/USBHDD1` by changing the `umask` and `dmask` (not recommended):

`mount -o remount,umask=000,dmask=000 /media/USBHDD1`

(3) Change the partition to a different file system.  Only do this if you're not accessing the the external hard drive from a windows computer:

You won't be able to convert the file system from VFAT to a Unix-compatible FS, so you'll have to backup the contents of the drive, format as EXT3+ or reiserfs, then copy the contents back.  *You can find tutorials for doing this on the web.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60204/discussion-between-myninjaname-and-l00kitsjake).

Comment: It may be a bit unsecure, but adding "umask=000,dmask=000" in the /etc/fstab file for the mounted drive that I serve with samba, solved the chown error. In my case the error was generated by the gitlab installer with docker-compose